# How to create next or react project of a specific version with PNPM?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app, pnpm

I use PNPM to create a `react-app` with this script :

```
pnpm create react-app react-app-name
```

and this script to create a next app :

```
pnpm create next-app --typescript
```

I was wondering how can I create a react app with specific version of 16 or a version 10 next app with PNPM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNPM `create` under the hood uses `dlx` to bootstrap projects from a *create-** or *@foo/create-** starter kit.

As same as you can specify version when using `dlx`, you can specify version of `create` you want to use as:

```bash
> pnpm create next-app@9.3.2 next-app
> pnpm create next-app@latest next-app
```

---

However, I didn't see in version of these dependencies change when another version of template is specified. So I manually downgraded dependencies with:

```bash
pnpm upgrade next@10 # Specifies version 10 of Next (downgrades from 13 to 10)
```

It may also state that peer dependencies are unmeet so you can use same approach as above until dependencies for whole project are satisfied.